# How to redirect a text file output into a pipe?

Tags: linux, shell, unix, pipe

I am running a Unix tool that takes an option `-l log_file`. I would like to redirect that into a pipe, something like this:

```
my_tool -l /dev/tty | grep "Aye, Caramba!"
```

Unfortunately, when I specify `/dev/tty` the `my_tool`'s output goes directly to the console window, bypassing `grep`.

I also tried `/dev/stdout`, to no avail.

Thus the question: what do I need to specify for the option `-l` above in order to capture the corresponding output into the pipe?

Comment: What happens if you do `my_tool -l /dev/stdout` without a pipe? Does it log to stdout? If not, there's something else going on with `my_tool`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [process substitution](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html) to create a file handle that pipes any contents written to the handle through a command pipeline.

For example, this should work:

```
my_tool -l >(grep "Aye, Caramba!" > path/to/store/partial.log)
```

This passes `my_tool` a `/dev/fd/XXX` path which it can write to. Any contents written to that path are piped through `grep` and then written to the `partial.log` file.

Functionally this is similar to Kenster's suggestion to use named pipes, but process substitution is often easier to work with and reason about, in my opinion.

Answer (score 2):

You could try using a [named pipe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Named_pipe):

```
mkfifo pipe
grep "Aye, Caramba!" pipe &
my_tool -l pipe
```

In this example, grep will open `pipe` for reading, which will block until another process opens it for writing. When my_tool writes data into the pipe, grep will be able to read the data. Once my_tool closes `pipe`, grep will get an end-of-file indication and exit.

Answer (score 0):

It might be useful to run one process generating the log, and another following the log being created and grepping its output

To do it that way, in one console you could run my_tool, generating the desired log.

```
my_tool -l /tmp/mylog
```

Then in a different console you could run:

```
tail -f -n+0 /tmp/mylog | grep --line-buffered the_pattern_to_match
```

`tail` will print the "last" lines of the file passed as argument. `-n+0`  tells tail to process the full file up to where it has been written. `-f` tell tail to keep the file open and keep sending whatever arrives to standard output (in this case redirected to the pipe).

Then in grep you will want the `--line-buffered` so it does not wait for tail to finish before it prints its own output.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try `my_tool -l /dev/stdout | grep`

Also as Zach suggested, the command itself may support some other option.